# Copy files from SD Card to SD Card's desire folder

Tags: android, audio-recording

I am new on Android. I want to copy my files from one location of SD Card to my Particular Folder. Using Default Voice Recording it stores default in SD Card but I would want to copy from there and store those files in my desire folder "sdcard>myfolder1>myfolder2"

Here's My Code:

```
btn_recordAudio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION);
            startActivityForResult(intent, RQS_RECORDING);

        }

    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RQS_RECORDING) {

        savedUri = data.getData();

        Toast.makeText(AudioRnp.this, "Saved: " + savedUri.getPath(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: u want to copy ur file into sd card !!!!!!

Comment: I have already done... :) Now my problem was solved.. ! Thank U.. :)